# Using a Single Variable for Multiple Values in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

Using Grafana, I am trying to figure out how to use a single variable in a SQL statement using a table that will be populated with different values.  For example, I have two "Stat" visualizations configured to provide a single value count; Hidden and Downloaded

[image]

If I click on Hidden, I want the table to show processes that have a hidden attribute set.  If I click on Downloaded, I want the table to show running processes that were downloaded.

My SQL statement is:

```
select process, path, md5 
from proctable
$procTest
group by 1,2,3;
```

I want the variable $procTest to be replaced with "hidden is true" or "downloaded is true" depending on which single value is clicked.

I spent a great deal of time trying to figure out how to do this. I am currently using a data link to accomplish this, but I am using a variable for each.  This will become difficult to manage once I start adding more single values.

Is this something that can be done using Grafana?